UML стрелка зависимость, ассоциация
Допустим у меня есть
class TCreator
{
public:
    T* createT();
}

class T {...}

Мне обозначить связь между этими классами как зависимость или как ассоциацию, просто открыл книжку по паттернам банды 4, а именно фабричный метод, а там связь обозначена ассоциацией, как я слышал ее используют когда возможен переход от одного к другому, я думал это значит что класс должен иметь другой внутри себя (например указатель на него) или как вычислимый атрибут,  но тут речь идет о создании

Можно ли нарисовать так и куда лучше поставить стрелку, между наследниками или между родителями?

В итоге как правильнее всего, или нет разницы
